# What means that two arrows are equivalent?

Tags: category-theory

I've just asked a lateral question about this, and someone gave me a very useful answer to a beginner of category theory like me: *Two arrows are equivalent in a specific category $C$ if they are isomorphic as objects in the arrow category Arr($C$)*. What is the intuitive idea behind that?

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense to me; what is “the arrow category”? The singular definite article suggests a *specific* category, but I don’t know what it’s supposed to refer to.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Here is the definition:https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category#:~:text=Every%20category%20C%20gives%20rise,hence%20the%20name)%20of%20C.

Comment: So it’s not “the arrow category”. It’s “The arrow category **of $\mathbf{C}$**”. Important to have that “last name”, so make it clear that it is not an absolute object, but a relative one. It’s nothing more than a functor category $\mathbf{C}^{I}$. You view morphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ as functors from the diagram category, and you declare two morphisms “equivalent” when there is a natural isomorphism between them viewing them as functors.

Comment: The “intuition” is just the usual one: when you have an isomorphism between objects in a category, you think of the objects as equivalent: anything you can say, categorically, about one you can say about the other, mediated by the isomorphism. This category treats the morphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ as objects, and so in that context, two objects are isomorphic if and only if there is an isomorphism between them.

Comment: If you unwind what that means in $\mathbf{C}$, it just says that you have two morphisms $a\colon X\to Y$, $a’\colon X’\to Y’$, and isomorphisms $f\colon X\to X’$, $g\colon Y\to Y’$ that make $a,a’$ correspond to one another: $a = g^{-1}\circ a’\circ f$.

Comment: What was the "lateral question"?

Comment: Probably [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/388794) the OP posted earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, two objects are “essentially the same” (as far as the category $\mathbf{C}$ is concerned) if there is an isomorphism between them.

If you unwind the definition you were given, it says that if you have two morphisms/arrows in $\mathbf{C}$,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
X&\stackrel{a}{\longrightarrow}&Y\\
X’&\stackrel{a’}{\longrightarrow}&Y’
\end{array}$$
then when are they “essentially the same”? When you can make the domains are isomorphic, the codomains are isomorphic, *and* the two maps correspond to one another under these isomorphisms. That is, there exist an isomorphism $f\colon X\to X’$, and isomorphism $g\colon Y\to Y’$, and
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{a}>>Y\\
@V{f}VV@VVgV\\
X’@>{a’}>>Y’
\end{CD}$$
commutes. That is, $a = g^{-1}\circ a’\circ f$, so that what you can say about $a$ you can likewise say about $a’$ by “translating” using $f$ and $g$ (or $f$ and $g^{-1}$) which are isomorphisms. So that if you think of $X$, $Y$, and $a$ as the “English version”, and you think of $f$ and $g$ as “translating into Esperanto”, say, then $a’$ is the translation of $a$ into Esperanto using $f$ and $g$ to do the translation.

Comment: I found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Arrow_category, that we can define the arrow category of $C$ through the comma category $1_C \downarrow 1_C$. In the comma category, f and g need not be isomorphisms, so, is not correct to define the equivalence of morphisms that you mentioned using the arrow category of C?, or is there some detail I'm missing?

Comment: @JohnMars: You don't need them to be isomorphisms to have a morphism in the comma category. But to assert that $a$ and $a'$ are isomorphic means that you have maps $f$ and $g$ as above, and you have maps $f'$ and $g'$ going in the opposite direction; and composing $f'f$ and $g'g$ gives the identity map on $a$ (which means $f'f=\mathrm{id}_X$ and $g'g=\mathrm{id}_Y$), and that composing $ff'$ and $gg'$ gives the identity map on $a'$ (which amounts to $ff'=\mathrm{id}_{X'}$ and $gg'=\mathrm{id}_{Y'}$). So then $f$ is an isomorphism with inverse $f'$, $g$ is an iso with inverse $g'$.